# MongoDB Compass Aggregation

Tags: mongodb

Hi I trying to figure out how to iterate through a column value having more than 1 object. More specifically I am trying to figure out How many Countries have more than TWO languages listed?

Here is a snipet of data.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9Yto.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit of a guess as to how to get what is within the objects for 'languages', but to get  count you can use the [$objectToArray](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)
Look at your data:
[Quick look at your data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVoN6.png)
The languages field is an object with 0 or more keys. $objectToArray will create a element for each object key along with the key value.
Just get the $size of that array.

```
[{$addFields: {
 reivew_count: {
  $size: {
   $objectToArray: '$review_scores'
  }
 }
}}]
```